# Google Checkout custom form inputs

Tags: google-checkout

I have google checkout setup, along with the server-side php responsehandler that is writing successful transaction info to the database. All I want to do is send some information silently from the Google Checkout form to the responsehandler.

When I try to put custom form inputs like:

```
<input name="my_custom_tag_name" value="my_custom_value"/>
```

Google appears to purposely ignore them since my responsehandler never sees them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.merchant-private-data" value="MyOrder#123">
```

Reference: https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=64729